# Trying to follow schematic for the first time, getting weird result

Tags: avr

So I am trying to follow this circuit diagram to implement V-USB for my ATmega8:

[image]

I was trying to attach C4, like this (I left out all the other connections just to keep it simple):

[image]

Now, the problem is the wire connecting the VCC pin of the AVR to the ground rail. Judging by the circuit schematic, it looks like that is what I have to do. But the circuit doesn't work right this way. The power just seems to fade away (I have an LED connected to the voltage and ground rail of the breadboard, and it just fades out every time I connect the power source).

But, when I take out the ground wire, everything works just great. So I think that's the way to do it, and I found it very weird to be connecting the ground wire in the same line as the power anyways. I want to know why it doesn't work the way depicted above, and what the schematic actually intended for me to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the two lines at the far right of the schematic, they cross each other rather than connect. Notice there is no junction dot. Vcc should never be connected to ground as it creates a short across the power supply.
If you mean the capacitor connection (C4), then that should work fine, if you are using an electrolytic (it should be a 100nF ceramic but your picture shows an electrolytic) make sure it's the right way around. It needs to be parallel between Vcc and GND, not in series with Vcc and the Vcc pin (and Vcc pin to ground?) as I think you may have it in the picture.

To summarise:

- Connect pin 20 to V+ rail
- Connect pin 10 to ground rail.
- Connect 100nF capacitor between pin 20 and pin 10.

Comment: Thanks! Is it okay if I use electrolytic instead?

Comment: It's not ideal, but it should probably work (if you get intermittent issues whilst running, then suspect this) Make sure you have the polarity correct though (+ lead to Vcc) Definitely get some ceramic capacitors (plenty of 100nF and 1uF) for future use.

Comment: I do have the polarity correct. Actually, I do have ceramic ones (the orange circular looking ones I believe). I'll just use those. Don't have to worry about polarity either, right? Thanks again.

Comment: Just to confirm, 100nF = 0.1uF?

Comment: Yep, 100nF = 0.1uF. Use the ceramic, no polarity and better suited for C4's purpose.